# Why does the map size change?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stl

```
class Solution {
 public:
  bool checkInclusion(string s1, string s2) {
    int m = s1.size();
    int n = s2.size();
    unordered_map<char, int> s1_freq;
    unordered_map<char, int> s2_freq;
    int match = 0;
    for (char s : s1) {
      s1_freq[s]++;
    }
    cout << s1_freq.size() << endl << endl;
    int left = 0;
    int right = 0;
    int window = 0;
    while (left <= right && right < n) {
      s2_freq[s2[right]]++;
      window++;
      if (s1_freq.find(s2[right]) != s1_freq.end() &&
          s2_freq[s2[right]] == s1_freq[s2[right]]) {
        match++;
      }
      if (window == m) {
        cout << match << " " << s1_freq.size() << endl;
        if (match == s1_freq.size())
          return true;
        if (s2_freq[s2[left]] == s1_freq[s2[left]])
          match--;
        s2_freq[s2[left]]--;
        left++;
        window--;
      }
      right++;
    }
    return false;
  }
};
```

this is the output

```
2

0 2

0 3

1 4

2 5

1 5

0 5

0 6
```

sorry if the code is hard to read . I was trying to use sliding window to solve a problem involving finding if a permutation of s1 exist in s2 . i was using two maps . s1_freq is the unordered_map which has the frequency count of s1.

the count of frequency is 2 after i inserted the elements .

here is the test case : s1 : "ab" and s2 : "eidbaooo"

but the size of the s1 map seem to change as evident by the output . i suspect on the first if condition inside while . coz the output was 4 5 5 6 6 6 or something similar when i didnt have the find check in it .

sorry if the question is badly phrased

Comment: *sorry if the code is hard to read* why do you make your code hard to read? Is your space key broken? Seriously, it is no wonder that this code has bugs.

Comment: `s1_freq[s2[right]]` potentially inserts elements into the map.

Comment: and here again `s1_freq[s2[left]]`

Comment: hey sorry @463035818_is_not_an_ai . I would love to hear what makes the code hard to read , is it the variable names . i would like the improve on it .

Comment: Whatmakesthecodehardtoreadistheabsenceofblankspaceinexpressions. Oh sorry. What makes the code hard to read is the absence of blank space in expressions

Comment: My guess is `if(s2_freq[s2[left]]==s1_freq[s2[left]])` is adding to `s1_freq` since `s2[left]` wasn't already in the map.

Comment: *this is the output* The shown code does not output anything.

Comment: I dont know what the code is supposed to do, but I am certain that you have far to many lookups in the maps. `s1_freq.find(s2[right])` returns an iterator to the element with key `s2[right]` in `s1_freq`, then in the very same experssion you call `s1_freq[s2[right]]` to look up the same element in the same map again.

Comment: And there is no output because the given code will not compile without headers. Add those and you'll find it won't link without `main`.  And when you write that `main`, make sure you feed in the inputs that trigger the misbehaviour rather than force the user to type it in. Users are notorious typo machines, so don't trust them to enter the inputs you want tested.

Comment: why would the size of the map not increase? Do you know that `std::map::operator[]` potentially iserts an element into the map? And why do you think its a problem that the size of the map increases?

Comment: thanks , @463035818_is_not_an_ai , i had expected the comparison to be the problem too. because adding the find reduced the size . i had to do it inside the inner left reduction condition too to fix the issue which i was glossing over . And , ill try to improve the readability and will use more spaces

Comment: I still do not understand the question. And I am not requesting you to modify the code further, but just for your information, ommiting the `{}` for the expression after `if` is also not helping for readability. And inconsistently ommitting the `{}` sometimes and sometimes using them is confusing

Comment: @user18025483 *Why does the map size change?* -- Because you wrote code to change the size of the map.  Use a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to determine where this is occurring.

Comment: You're using `operator[]` for the map all over the place in your code, and `operator[]` will insert into a map if the key does not exist.   You need to hunt down where the `operator[]` calls that you're making is causing an issue.

Comment: Please read [mre].

Comment: Your code to me clearly shows you dived into competitive coding without rally learning how to use C++ (e.g. passing strings by value).  Some good resources to learn C++ from are [learncpp.com](https://www.learncpp.com/) for your initial steps (it is very decent for an online tutorial). 
Then use [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) to lookup everything C++ has to offer. 
And finally use the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to keep up to date with how C++ evolves and how it is supposed to be used.

Comment: When you use things like std::map read the documentation on cppreference

Comment: `unordered_map<char, int> const& s1_freq_const = s1_freq;` and then use `s1_freq_const` everywhere and you'll find out what lines are changing the map.